# Bootstrap two columns bug with panel-body class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a 2 columns bootstrap layout (one for menu, and one for content).
It works well, but if I put a bootstrap panel (.panel-body precisely) it does a weird stuff (look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGUKs.png);

HTML:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.container-body {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 0px!important;
}
.container-body>.sidebar {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width:250px;
    float: left;
}
.container-body>.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container container-body">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">test:</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Why does this box follow sidebar size ?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap gives you all features to design a web ... why don't you try to use original bootstrap.min.css first then customize it. Using fixed width will force other width to behave unstable. besides, it won't be nice responsive. use % - say - 'width: 40%;'

Comment: Actually, this sidebar is optional, and has is visibility-hidden for small devices, unfortunately I should keep a width of 250px for advertising purpose :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a final and updated release, it provides very nice css to design a web easily. However, we could customize the bootstrap value based on our needs.
File includes: bootstrap.min.css, ~min.js, and sb-admin-2.css.

In your source-code, you use:

```
<div class="container container-body">
```

Here, I use wrapper to handle both columns, as in:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
            <li>AAAA</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
..............
```

this demo shows you how to do as your wish without writing our own codes:
Sorry, I give you the demo in **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/fq22h0em/)**.